# Lucene Creates a new .cfs file everytime I add to index

Tags: .net-core, lucene, lucene.net

Every time I commit adding a new document into the index a new _X.cfs file is created.

```
using (StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(LuceneVersion.LUCENE_48))
{
   using (IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(Directory)
   {

      Document doc = new Document();

      doc.Add(new TextField("Id", Id.ToString(), Lucene.Net.Documents.Field.Store.YES))
      doc.Add(new TextField("Symbol", Symbol, Lucene.Net.Documents.Field.Store.NO))
      doc.Add(new TextField("Channel",  Channel, Lucene.Net.Documents.Field.Store.NO))

      writer.AddDocument(doc);
      writer.Commmit();
  }
}
```

I have a process running where there will be 1000s of docuemnts being indexed a day (at different times). This way there will be 1000s of new .cfs files in my directory.

What is the solution for this?

I am using Lucene.NET version 4.8.0-beta00014

Answer (score 0):

Inserting 1000s of docs is no problem.  On my local my dev box I can insert around 14K docs per second.  Of course the speed will depend greatly on the size of the documents and the speed of the machine.

Lucene manages the segments well and will merge them periodically.  The result will be less segments but bigger segments.  You can make Lucene's life easier and your indexing faster by not calling `Flush`, `Commit` or `MaybeRefreshBlocking` until after you have inserted the set of documents you desire.  (These commands force buffered documents to be written out in a new segment).  But even if you call all these methods after each time you add a document to the index Lucene will still manage the segments well by doing merging as needed. It will just be much slower (maybe like 20 docs per second).